# Strange Raspberry PI SD card behaviour

Tags: raspberry-pi

My raspberry 1 pi has raspbian on Sandisk Extreme 32GB.
It is working well in the Raspberry, OS boots, no problem, however, if I shut it down, and insert into ubuntu laptop, I see error JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdb2-8. and I cannot read it.
First time I noticed a year ago. Raspberry pi still working without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

More details would help to identify your problem more accurately.
But it souds like you may have to run fsck in order to fix filsystem errors.
here is an example for running fsck if your partition is on sdb2 :

> sudo fsck /dev/sdb2

It's always recommended to take a backup first.

Comment: Ok, I will try, but that would not work on my laptop, since the sd card is not seen in fdisk -l at all (it is disconnected soon after I insert it, I see it in dmesg, and I see this error  JBD2: Error -5 detected ..). Other SD cards are seen ok on laptop. 
I will try this command on raspberry, on which this card is working ok.:)